# $\{w \in \{ 0,1 \}^{*}: w \text{ contains both 101 and 010 as substrings} \}$

Tags: automata

The questions is to build a transition diagram for nondeterministic finite automata that accepts the language of all strings that contain both 101 and 010 as substrings. This is what I came up with but I am not sure if it is right:

[image]

Secondly, what is the point of the epsilons. Why not replacing them with the symbol (0 or 1). I hope it is clear what I mean.

Comment: Do you mean a NFA to read the language of strings with both of those as substrings?

Comment: With both, not either @DonThousand

Comment: Do overlaps count?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by overlaps? @DonThousand

Comment: Is $0101$ a valid string.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. No, that would not count. @DonThousand

Comment: In that case, yes, this works.

Comment: So my transition diagram would be correct? Also could you explain the point of the epsilons? Like why not replacing them with 1 and 0 for the first two transitions for example?

Comment: Or why do I need the last epsilon transition. Couldn't I just make two accept states (which would be the last transition for each branch)?

Comment: That's correct. You don't really need either epsilon transition, really. Again, there is no case in which epsilons are necessary, it's just that sometimes it is easier to write a NFA with one.

Comment: Actually, I guess I need the first epsilon transition due to the fact that there can be stuffed 0s or 1s at the beginning. The last transitions I could remove and add a loop for 0s and 1s at both accept states... Do you agree?

Comment: Actually you are right. I could remove both of them...

Comment: I disagree: $0101$ contains $101$ and $010$ as a substring and hence should be accepted.

Comment: Related (but different) [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2360921/give-a-regex-that-matches-this-specific-language).